# How to use checkbox in loop in react native

Tags: react-native

How to use checkbox in loop with diffrent key when i use in loop and click on any one after than check all loop checkbox give me solution

Answer (score 1):

You can create an array of solutions in state:

```
...
state.solutions = [
  {value:false},
  {value:false},
  {value:false}  
]
```

Create a changes event handler:

```
changeEvent = (ev, index) => {
  let tmp_solution = [...state.solutions];
  tmp_solutions[index].value = !tmp_solutions[index].value;
  this.setState({solutions: tmp_solution})
}
```

Create the checkboxes render function:

```
const checkBoxes = this.state.solutions.map((index) =>{
  return(
    <CheckBox 
      value={this.state.solutions[index].value} 
      onValueChange={(ev) => this.changeEvent(ev, index)} key={index} 
    />
  )
});
```

Render all the checkboxes:

```
render() {
  <View>
    {checkBoxes}
  </View>
}
...
```

sorry if there are errors

Answer (score 0):

Well, suppose that you have a data, so you can use map to do that. In order to save the answers also you can use index in setSetate as below. I use the `react-native-checkbox-heaven` component to have the check Box:

```
import CheckBox from 'react-native-checkbox-heaven';
renderContentCheckBox=()=>{
         console.log("[renderContent] your data", this.state.data);
            return Object.keys(this.state.data).map(function (item, index) {

              return (<View key={index} style={{  alignItems: 'flex-start', justifyContent: 'flex-start', width: Dimensions.get('window').width / 1.1, }}>
                       <CheckBox
                        label={item.title}
                        labelStyle={styles.labelStyle}
                        iconSize={28}
                        iconName='matMix'
                        checked={this.state.check1}
                        checkedColor='#44FF00'
                        uncheckedColor='#FFFFFF'
                        onChange={(val) => {(value) => { that.setState({ ["CheckBox" + index]: value,   }); console.log("radio" + index, value);
                            }}
                        />

                    </View>
                   );
            }
}
```

Then you can use it inside the render:

```
render() {

return (<View>
  {this.renderContentCheckBox(this)}
    </View>
 );
}
```